# XBox Gold Cancellation Policy for Reduced Cost Games

Tags: xbox-one, xbox-network

I know that if you cancel your XBox Gold membership, you'll no longer be allowed to play free games you've downloaded as a result of having it.

How does this work for games you got at a reduced price though? Do you need to pay the difference in cost in order to play them again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My search for an answer isn't coming up with a hard-set rule, but from personal experience: **No, once you've bought the games (even at reduced pricing), they are yours to play and keep.**

This is based on a currently lapse Xbox360 account, but also precedent from other services like Steam and PS+. A reduced cost game due to membership is akin to that of a sale price.  Even if you only paid a penny, you still paid for a license and that license is the same one as if you paid full price.  *You will not need to pay the difference*.

That said, while your account is expired, you will not get access to any of the "membership only" sale prices as well. (so buying a new game or DLC will be in their full pricing, even if the base game was at reduced pricing for members.)

Comment: Sounds reasonable to me, thanks! I'd just bought a new game last night at a reduced cost and got to thinking about how this would work. What you say does make sense though!